# Understanding when to use a subquery over a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I seem to be missing something. I keep reading that you should use a join instead of a sub-select in most articles I read. However running a quick experiment myself shows a big win for the sub-query when it comes down to execution time.

Trying to get all first names of people that have made a bid (I presume the tables speak for themselves) results in the follwing.

This join takes 10 seconds

```
select U.firstname
from Bid B
inner join [User] U on U.userName = B.[user]
```

This query with sub-query takes 3 seconds

```
select firstname
from [User]
where userName in (select [user] from bid)
```

Why is my experiment not in line with what I keep reading everywhere or am I missing something?

Experimenting on I found that execution times are the same after adding distinct to both.

Comment: Both Select will probably return a different number of rows, the join will return the same firstname once per bid while the IN returns the name only once no matter how many bids were done. To get the same result you need to add DISTINCT (assuming that firstname is unique, otherwise you can't get the same result without adding additional columns/PK), which might slow down the join even more.

Comment: Ideally, SQL Server will generate the same optimal plan when queries are semantically the same. However, these queries are not semantically identical. The join will return the same row more than once if the joined columns are not unique.

Comment: Have a look at the execution plans, they will tell you how the optimizer processed the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Read for Subquery vs Inner Join
https://www.essentialsql.com/subquery-versus-inner-join/

Comment: Even know others seem to have put more effort into an answer this is the one that helped me the most understanding the underlying principles.

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same thing.  In the query with joins you can potentially multiply rows or have rows entirely removed from the results.

Inner Join removes rows on non-matched keys.  It also multiplies rows on any matched keys that repeat in either one or both tables being joined.  Inner Join therefor goes through the additional step of multiplying and removing rows.

The subquery you used is a SELECT.  Since there are no filters using a WHERE it is as fast as a simple SELECT and since there are no joins you get results as fast as the results can be selected.

Some may argue that Outer joins return NULLs similar to sub-queries- but they can still multiply rows.  Hence, sub-queries and joins are not the same thing.

In the queries you provided, you want to use the 2nd query (the one with the subquery) since it doesn't multiply or remove rows.